# Program crashes after update but works fine with clean install

Tags: wix, updates

I made a C# wpf program and at this point I have an update ready to release. I created an installer with the Wix Toolkit. So I can make the msi file. But when I do the upgrade from version 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 the program crashes after installation. If I first delete the c# program with version 1.0.0.0 and then install version 2.0.0.0 everything works fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong. this is my Product.wxs (my guid ids are in my program real ids):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?define ProductVersion="3.0.0.0"?>
  <?define View_TargetDir=$(var.View.TargetDir)?>
  <?define UpgradeCode="GUID-ID-FOR-UPGRADE"?>
  <!-- 
  Version 1.0
  <Product Id="GUID-ID-1" 
           Name="MIDIMACRO" 
           Language="1033" 
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="vanlooverenkoen" 
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  -->

  <!--
  Version 2.0
  -->
  <Product Id="GUID-ID-2"
           Name="MIDIMACRO"
           Language="1033"
           Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
           Manufacturer="vanlooverenkoen"
           UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">



    <Package InstallerVersion="200" 
             Compressed="yes" 
             InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Icon Id="icon.ico" 
          SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)Icon.ico" />
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" 
              Value="icon.ico" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" 
                 Value="Images\installer_top-banner.bmp" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" 
                 Value="Images\installer_background.bmp" />

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" 
              Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" 
               Control="Finish" 
               Event="DoAction" 
               Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed
      </Publish>
    </UI>

    <MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
                  DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MIDIMACRO" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProgramFilesFolder_files" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />
    </Feature>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch MIDIMACRO" />

    <!-- Step 3: Include the custom action -->
    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]MIDIMACRO.exe" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MIDIMACRO" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="MIDIMACRO" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="9bd13330-6540-406f-a3a8-d7f7c69ae7f9">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="MIDIMACRO" Description="MIDIMACRO" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MIDIMACRO.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MIDIMACRO" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="cde1e030-eb64-49a5-b7b8-400b379c2d1a">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="MIDIMACRO" Description="MIDIMACRO" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MIDIMACRO.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MIDIMACRO" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
      <Component Id="MahApps.Metro.dll" Guid="7903f312-19fb-45a5-8dc6-9823ada4cca0">
        <File Id="MahApps.Metro.dll" Name="MahApps.Metro.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MahApps.Metro.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" Guid="4af9d18a-6205-4b23-887c-bf31685d548e">
        <File Id="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" Name="System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Guid="a97d5ecb-a716-43da-bd5f-83a7be929b47">
        <File Id="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Sanford.Multimedia.Midi.dll" Guid="e098aa86-d81e-48e9-84ba-4bc548e3f074">
        <File Id="Sanford.Multimedia.Midi.dll" Name="Sanford.Multimedia.Midi.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Sanford.Multimedia.Midi.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Controller.dll" Guid="2d5d325c-234a-4ae4-b3fb-c87d346fccf5">
        <File Id="Controller.dll" Name="Controller.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Controller.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="View.exe.config" Guid="e1f88ab9-55fb-4bcc-a88c-2834c63469e6">
        <File Id="View.exe.config" Name="MIDIMACRO.exe.config" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)View.exe.config" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="View.exe" Guid="7388a307-32fa-4f56-8fc6-a558de5ab7e6">
        <File Id="View.exe" Name="MIDIMACRO.exe" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)View.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Model.dll" Guid="2684cc98-d124-41d4-85e6-99ecc2c7e131">
        <File Id="Model.dll" Name="Model.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Model.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll" Guid="ccbfeca9-31fe-4d5c-a31a-5a264f69fd58">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll" Name="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.dll" Guid="66e05999-a097-4595-bffe-99e4afef2369">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.dll" Name="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignColors.dll" Guid="28ef4cb6-386f-4c82-8999-39ff3e1cde9a">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignColors.dll" Name="MaterialDesignColors.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignColors.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="WindowsInput.dll" Guid="0a28ba53-41df-42b0-b997-cc7e86a47180">
        <File Id="WindowsInput.dll" Name="WindowsInput.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)WindowsInput.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll" Guid="1f4aaa97-ed7c-4d12-ac25-d5b0ba0fb734">
        <File Id="Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll" Name="Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="CSCore.dll" Guid="6dcfcc86-12d8-42f6-a297-87560a5a3182">
        <File Id="CSCore.dll" Name="CSCore.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)CSCore.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb" Guid="9bf8b60e-6944-4e65-b2e6-35d826ffff3d">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb" Name="MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll" Guid="1e4cf4a5-ec59-41de-b42a-1de602185483">
        <File Id="System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll" Name="System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="System.Reactive.Linq.dll" Guid="3253a150-0b73-4dde-902e-93ecb4f3039b">
        <File Id="System.Reactive.Linq.dll" Name="System.Reactive.Linq.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)System.Reactive.Linq.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll" Guid="02c68719-7df6-4814-ab49-c5c2660448c4">
        <File Id="System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll" Name="System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="System.Reactive.Core.dll" Guid="11757dde-fbdc-489b-8de5-2e12bbdce7c0">
        <File Id="System.Reactive.Core.dll" Name="System.Reactive.Core.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)System.Reactive.Core.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignColors.pdb" Guid="b689cffb-a71f-45a1-83cd-97e9e265d491">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignColors.pdb" Name="MaterialDesignColors.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignColors.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="View.pdb" Guid="d8b9af45-0c0d-4cb3-b5e2-8b2cfe3e66cf">
        <File Id="View.pdb" Name="View.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)View.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.pdb" Guid="0623abd7-239e-41b3-aa8c-e0c76272eb0d">
        <File Id="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.pdb" Name="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Firebase.Database.dll" Guid="598ae72f-65e9-4b12-a88f-480e47c9f02c">
        <File Id="Firebase.Database.dll" Name="Firebase.Database.dll" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Firebase.Database.dll" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Controller.pdb" Guid="08fa8a12-2c45-4bf8-8d68-6d036117331d">
        <File Id="Controller.pdb" Name="Controller.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Controller.pdb" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="Model.pdb" Guid="1d408632-0906-4ef1-82d8-197b7665a03a">
        <File Id="Model.pdb" Name="Model.pdb" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)Model.pdb" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProgramFilesFolder_files" Directory="ProgramFilesFolder">

      <Component Id="resources_settings_icon.svg" Guid="7f417c29-b7f8-4282-b248-cb220436c6e0">

        <File Id="resources_settings_icon.svg" Name="settings_icon.svg" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)resources\settings_icon.svg" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="resources_search_icon.svg" Guid="12291d78-6c79-4b35-9435-025a7bd4b063">

        <File Id="resources_search_icon.svg" Name="search_icon.svg" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)resources\search_icon.svg" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="resources_flash_icon.svg" Guid="d84b95d6-bc6c-43d0-b7a3-15da8332cb2e">

        <File Id="resources_flash_icon.svg" Name="flash_icon.svg" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)resources\flash_icon.svg" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="resources_gesture_icon.svg" Guid="3e5d81c5-7801-4fb3-9dda-4ba1fb593a87">

        <File Id="resources_gesture_icon.svg" Name="gesture_icon.svg" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)resources\gesture_icon.svg" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="resources_add_circle_icon.svg" Guid="f56738c4-876a-4db3-8958-9d714450f1fa">

        <File Id="resources_add_circle_icon.svg" Name="add_circle_icon.svg" Source="$(var.View_TargetDir)resources\add_circle_icon.svg" />

      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: What the value of $(var.ProductVersion)?

Comment: <?define ProductVersion="3.0.0.0"?> all the defines are located at the top of my configuration

Comment: My guess is it is some unversioned component file that doesn't get installed and then after the upgrade you either have the old installer's file or no file at all. Can you run your upgrade again with logging turned on? `Msiexec /i UpgradeInstall.msi /l*v msilog.txt` Then look in the msilog for where the components and features are planned out to be installed or not. You can also edit your question to put the log portions or a link to the log here. You want to see "Installed: Absent; Request: Local; Action: Local" for all the new files/upgraded files.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4aJr1eVJ3kddUxnREIzb0hfdVk this is my log.  image.prntscr.com/image/097b1ddd6575431a86e35db10f0b309a.png this is what I found. but I have no Idea what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely issue is the message in the log:

Disallowing installation of component: {CCBFECA9-31FE-4D5C-A31A-5A264F69FD58} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists

This implies that you did not update the file version of that Dll. The result is that the Dll is missing and your app crashes. There's a good explanation here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2015/11/16/why-windows-installer-removes-files-during-a-major-upgrade-if-they-go-backwards-in-version-numbers/

The basic issue is that early in the install it decides that it won't overwrite that file because the existing version on the system is greater than the "new" incoming file, so it decides not to install it at all. Those are the file version overwrite rules. However, later on the upgrade occurs that removes all the old files, but it still erroneously sticks with the idea that it shouldn't install that file, so it's missing at the end of the install.

Comment: Or do I just always need to change the GUID for each component?

Comment: I read the whole article & related stackoverflow post but I don't get it how I can fix it.

Comment: after a couple of changes I got it working, still not 100% shure what the real problem was :s

Comment: After the second update nothing worked anymore, so I figured out another way to get the updates working. All the files need to be removed BEFORE instaling.